# php mysql syntax with IN

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, in-clause

Why dosnt this work:

```
$mystr = "1,2";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol IN (:mystr)');
$stmt->execute(['mystr' => $mystr]);`
```

When this does:

```
$mystr = "1,2";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycol IN ('.$mystr.')');
$stmt->execute();
```

Try and error and search the Internet

Comment: Because of the prepared statements. You have to bind parameters separately, or else it's treated as a single value. Your where now acts like `WHERE mycol IN ("1,2")` instead of `WHERE mycol IN ("1","2")`

Comment: READ the section called [Prepared statements and IN clause](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) in here

Comment: You need one parameter per value, you can't just parameterise the entire clause - it'll treat it as a single value if you do